# Does "all-month" mean "from month to month"?

Tags: word-usage, time, time-words

There is [*all-day*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/all-day), but I'm not sure whether *all-month* exists or means "from month to month" or not. I can use *month to month* too, but *all-month* seems more suited in this writing:

> No parenting book can help a mom to know whether her child playing Counter Strike **all-month** is a healthy hobby, an addiction to violence or a determination to become a professional gamer.

Comment: throughout the month.  **all month** is not hyphenated.  Nor is **all day** when it is adverbial, and means that something has been *happening* for the entire day. *This noise has been going on **all day.***  **all-day** when used as an adjective is hyphenated, *This allergy pill offers **all-day** relief*.

Comment: I don't think 'all month' means the same as 'from month to month'. If I saw the clause 'her child playing Counter Strike all-month', I would assume that he had played Counter Strike for a whole month. On the other hand, I would interpret "her child playing Counter Strike from month to month" to mean that he plays all month, every month. E.g. I pay rent for my home on a month-on-month basis, which means I have lived here for almost two years and I have paid rent at the beginning of each month each of those months..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is some hyperbole  (say *hi per bo lee*), a type of figurative speech in which you exaggerate for a dramatic effect. No child is *literally* playing all month.

So if this is hyperbole, why not say "all day" or "every day". These are the usual expressions, unless there is some reason to specify that "months" are significant to the meaning. If you know that "all day" exists is there any reason to use "all month"

> A child who plays violent video games all day may have developed an addiction.
>
> A child who fasts all month during Ramadan can develop an eating disorder.

An alternative is to use

> A child who has been playing Counterstrike for months on end...

Which preserves the sense of "for many months"

Comment: I just want to emphasize that the duration of addiction is counted by month, not day, because that's what constitute an addiction. Does "all day" work nevertheless?

Comment: See my edit to the answer